# Crash report, find the frame where app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i try to find out the place where the app crash. Can someone tell me in which frame the app crash? in my opinion should be 12 but i am not sure.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198d43270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198de1224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000198cbab14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197da1414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197dc0b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001985bc3bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197dbdbb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197dbd738 __cxa_rethrow + 140
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001985bc290 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018793d2a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 568
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000190a9f5a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
11  UIKit                           0x000000018c26e780 UIApplicationMain + 1484
12  New_Messager                    0x000000010006fa60 0x100044000 + 178784
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198c2aa04 start + 0
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Add an exception breakpoint into your project. It will stop the code just on the line that crashes your code.

[image]

Comment: Hot damn i didn't know you could do that. This is gonna help me SO MUCH when debugging apps ! Dude, thank you so much :)

Comment: your answer is not related with my question, was just another way, to thank you for reply my, but your answer is not helpfully at all...